# Изменить имя файла при загрузке на сервер

Tags: файлы, php

Нужно изменить имя файла при загрузке на сервер

Что имею:

```
 $folder =  'items/';//директория в которую будет загружен файл
 $ext = array_pop(explode('.',$_FILES['userfile']['name']));
 $named = preg_match($_FILES['userfile']);
 $new_name = item.'_'.time().'_'.$named.'.'.$ext;
 $uploadedFile = $folder.$new_name;
```

На входе: good.rar

На выходе: item _ 1407229647_.rar

Должно: item _ 1407229647_good.rar

Переменная $named неправильная, как исправить?

Comment: @Rammsteinik

    $named = preg_match($_FILES['userfile']);

что делает эта строчка?

Comment: Вроде выдаёт имя файла до точки

Comment: @Rammsteinik, я могу предоставить сразу три "нет" на выбор: эта функция не обрезает строки ни при каком использовании, эта функция возвращает булево значение, в эту функцию не подается название файла.

Comment: `$named = $_FILES['userfile'];` тоже не работает

Comment: Есть ли решение народ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$file = 'good.rar';
$fdata = pathinfo($file);

$ext = $fdata['extension']; // rar
$filename = $fdata['filename']; // good

$newname = 'item_' . time() . '_' . $filename . '.' . $ext;
echo $newname; // item_1407253287_good.rar
```